# Are positive real numbers $x,y$ allowed to be taken out during this proof?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

> Prove $$\left(x^2 - y^2\right)\left(\frac1y - \frac1x\right) \ge 0$$ where $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers.

Can I simplify $\frac{(x^2 - y^2)(x-y)}{xy} \ge 0$
and then $(x^2 - y^2)(x-y) \ge 0$ cancelling out the $xy$?

Is this valid because then 
\begin{align}
(x+y)(x-y)(x-y)&\ge  0\cdot(x-y)^2\ge 0
\end{align}
 which is always true and then prove backwards from here?

Comment: Check the edit, is this what you meant?

Comment: It is, I misread his first line and MathJaxed it wrong. Thanks @kingW3

Comment: If x and y are of the same sign, both positive or both negative, then xy is positive and, yes, multiplying both sides by xy will not change the direction of the inequality.  But if x and y have different signs, x negative and y positive or x positive and y negative, the xy is negative and multiplying both sides will reverse the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

If $x,y$ are positive, then $xy>0$; so, when you have

$$\frac{(x^2 - y^2)(x-y)}{xy} \ge 0$$

you're allowed to multiply by $xy$ (and the $\ge $ won't flip), to get

$$(x^2 - y^2)(x-y) \ge 0$$

And from that indeed you can get

$$(x^2 - y^2)(x-y)=(x+y)(x-y)(x-y)=(x+y)(x-y)^2 \ge 0$$

which is true, since $x+y>0$ and $(x-y)^2\ge 0$.